# What contains poison that you give and take?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

What contains poison that you give and take?
Where words and actions can make or break
Shared with all and made opaque
Or kept inside for others' sake

*The solution is a single-word answer.*

Comment: My suggestion for a title revision is to make it clear that this is the actual goal, and that the body content is just details. Otherwise, lead-in text and/or a final line would be a good idea.

Comment: @feelinferrety I'm happy with this now. I feel I've done what I can, so we'll see what the community thinks now.

Comment: \*stamps\* APPROVED!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the answer is

> opinions

What contains poison that you give and take?

> The word "poison" is inside "opinions", and you can *give* an opinion or *take* someone's opinion into account

Where words and actions can make or break
Shared with all and made opaque
Or kept inside for others' sake

> You can bare your opinion for all to see with words or actions, but unpopular opinions might be offensive to some people so it's sometimes advisable to keep them to yourself.

Comment: This has got to be it

Comment: @benzene indeed it is it

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> balloons (8 letters if you don't count the s)

which contain

> carbon dioxide

Comment: Not the right answer, sorry

Comment: It could be LUNGS.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay A previous edit said it had 8 letters. I was thinking it could be _lungfull_, though

Answer (score 1):

Well, if taken literally,

> it could be 'breathes'

For

What contains poison that you give and take?

> Exhale contains CO2 (a poisonous gas) and take - is for inhale

Where words and actions can make or break

> While speaking words, one has to inhale / exhale as well that is breathe and sometimes we may lose words (or breath itself, while talking)

Shared with all and made opaque

> In a quarrel, while doing a verbal exchange - which tarnishes (opaque) one's image and

Or kept inside for others' sake

> We should hold (or kept) our beathe for others who  depend on us / whom we are dear to !